# Re-captcha's widget buttons reload the whole page

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I have Google's re-captcha implemented and working in Chrome perfectly (AJAX APIs). IE is the problem...

I have: **localhost://myapp/index.html** and a link for *Forgot your password*. When this link is clicked jQuery click handler is called. Handler function changes the div's content and also calls for **Recaptcha.create(...)** The widget is displayed correctly and works as expected in Chrome, but in IE if I click on reload icon or the sound button it reloads the whole page.

If I manually call for Recaptcha.reload() it reloads without any problem ?!

HTML I have is:

```
<div id="recaptcha" style="width:120px"></div>

[...]

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>

[...]

//In a jquery click handler I call
Recaptcha.create("6LxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxIrpV5RO8P",
                    "recaptcha",
                    {
                        theme:'white',
                        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                    }
            );
```

So far so good... Captcha gets loaded well in all browsers. In IE8 and 9 when I click the widgets buttons for reload and mp3 version the whole page gets reloaded

I tried changing *http* for *https* and vice-versa, but still without any luck...

Answer (score 2):

When `Recaptcha.create();` is called, Google's re-captcha RELOAD and IMAGE/TEXT buttons' code looks something like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload();">
```

and I don't know why the page gets reloaded in my app in IE when the button is pressed and in the  demo Google provided [DEMO](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax) it sends a async request...

Since I can't change the javascript in *href* attribute I had to add a *onclick* handler in jQuery `$(document).ready();`

My solution was this:

```
$("#recaptcha).on("click", "id_of_the_reload_button", function(e){
    e.preventDEfault();
    Recaptcha.reload();
});
```

I basically blocked the natural behavior of the anchor google provides and called the reload() function myself.
I've never found out what was causing my page to reload in the first place